# XMPPFramework - Update profile nickname

Tags: ios, xmpp, xmppframework

I am using XMPPFramework to implement a jabber client communicating with an OpenFire server. So far everything has been working smoothly.

But now I want to change my profile's nickname or rather the 'displayName' as the client retrieves it from XMPPUserCoreDataStorageObject.

My first attempt was to use the VCardTempModule to update My VCard like this:

```
if (nickname) {
    [myVCard setNickname:nil];
    [myVCard setNickname:nickname];
}
[self.xmppvCardTempModule updateMyvCardTemp:myVCard];
```

It seems the server is updated, as the client receives the profile's tempVCard with the updated nickname:

```
RECV: <iq xmlns="jabber:client" type="result" from="myAccount@foo.com" to="myAccount@foo.com/564aa046"><vCard xmlns="vcard-temp"><PHOTO><BINVAL>{some binary image data}</BINVAL></PHOTO><NICKNAME>{my updated nickname}</NICKNAME></vCard></iq>
```

However, the updated nickname is nowhere to be found in other clients, while the photo is updated just fine using the XMPPVCardAvatar Module.

Has anyone a clue, what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: nobody even interested in this question?

Comment: same problem happening to me.  i m doing this  XMPPvCardTemp *newvCardTemp = [XMPPvCardTemp vCardTempFromElement
                                       :vCardXML];
        
        [newvCardTemp setNickname:jidField.text];
        
        [[objDelegate xmppvCardTempModule] updateMyvCardTemp
         :newvCardTemp]; way it sends iq as same as u send. but my nickname not updated

Comment: do u know how to do that

Comment: Sorry, still no clue. Development of that app is currently on hold.

Comment: ok no prob.if u will do anything regarding group discussion then please let me know.. thanks